# Change overlap order for SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

Change overlap order for SWRevealViewController

We call home view as front view, and sidebar view as rear view;

My question is, can we change just the overlap, say the sidebar is on top, and the home view is under sidebar? This does not change anything else, just too change the visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

In viewController where you need to do this add following line of code.

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.sidebarview];

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No this does not work. I guess you are not quite familiar with SWRevealViewController?

Comment: NO I am not. Sorry, I thought it is one of your classes.